# Draw an object in template using Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I would like to use a directive to draw a triangle above a serie of div

I have four squares and two values : `charge` and `normal`

`charge` is used to determine the color of squares.
`normal` to draw triangle

I have created a directive to make that

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[squareChart]'
})
export class SquareChartDirective implements OnInit {
  colors = {
    1: '#13a09b',
    2: '#13a03c',
    3: '#eceb1d',
    4: '#d40f0f'
  };
  @Input() charge: number;
  @Input() normal: number;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.highlight(this.charge);
  }
  private highlight(charge: number) {
    let colorCode = Math.trunc(charge / 25) + 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= colorCode; i++) {
      if (this.el.nativeElement.id === `sqr${i}`) {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.colors[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My component

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div squareChart id="sqr1" [charge]="actualCharge" [normal]="norm" class="p-2 bd-highlight square" >
    </div>
    <div squareChart id="sqr2" [charge]="actualCharge" [normal]="norm" class="p-2 bd-highlight square" >
    </div>
    <div squareChart id="sqr3" [charge]="actualCharge" [normal]="norm" class="p-2 bd-highlight square" >
    </div>
    <div squareChart id="sqr4" [charge]="actualCharge" [normal]="norm" class="p-2 bd-highlight square">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example is norm = 60 the down triangle should be above the third square ( if 25 so above second etc.. )

Example

[image]

I don't see how to do it from the same directive.

Another solution could be have a first row for triangles and a second row for squares but I don't think it's the best choice.

Here's [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxcra1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a component instead. In the component template you can conditionally hide or show the triangle.

(I probably did not get your logic right, but that's not the point, I think)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'square-chart',
  template: '<div [ngClass]="{hidden: !mark}" class="triangle"></div><div [ngStyle]="{background:background}" class="p-2 bd-highlight square"></div>',
})
export class SquareComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() i: number;
  @Input() charge: number;
  @Input() normal: number;
  mark = false;
  background;
  colors = {
    1: '#13a09b',
    2: '#13a03c',
    3: '#eceb1d',
    4: '#d40f0f'
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.background = this.colors[this.i];
    this.mark = +this.i === 2;
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kfmgg?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a triangle using a `Canvas` or an `SVG` element using `absolute` positioning, all within your `directive`. To make absolute positioning work, the parent element needs to be positioned `relative` to the viewport.

```
.square {
  position: relative;
  ...
}
```

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bc83je?file=src/app/square.directive.ts): Within `SquareChartDirective` class, you may switch from current `drawSVGMarker` to `drawCanvasMarker` method as you wish.

Comment: It should be drawn depending on normal  percentage value every square represents 25% ( 4 squares ) so triangle should be dynamic

Comment: OK, got condition check by checking `hansmaad's` answer and changed my `StackBlitz` accordingly